# Regex formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex format for a phone number sample 012-3456789.

```
malaysianPhoneRegex = "^[0]{1}[0-9]{2}[\\-]{1}[0-9]{7,8}$";
```

Now I want it to be able to accept 012-3456789 or 0123456789 or 012 345 6789 or 012 3456789

How do I do it, I am still learning on regex.

Comment: Try adding some examples of regex patterns you have tried but are not working for you.

Comment: There are a dozen or more questions on SO about parsing phone numbers with regexp. Search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the space, hyphen inside the character class and then make it as optional.

```
malaysianPhoneRegex = "^0[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /^[0]{1}[0-9]{2}[ \-]{0,1}[0-9]{3} {0,1}[0-9]{4}$/;
test = function(string) {
  console.log(string + ': ' + regex.test(string));
}
test("012-3456789");
test("0123456789");
test("012 345 6789");
test("012 3456789");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/\d*([- ]*)\d/g`

Working demo here - http://regexr.com/3aouv

mark it as answer if it helps